# Why can I use printf() when including iostream?

Tags: c++, printf, iostream

This piece of codes works fine even with minGW compiler under C++11 standards:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("haha");
    return 0;
}
```

Why should this work? I didn't include `stdio.h` but I can use functions like `printf()` and `rand()`. Are they included in `iostream`? At least I didn't find them included. If you say that it's included in `iostream`, show me the evidence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's implementation defined if that works or not.

The implementation may include additional headers it needs, but you as a developer should not rely on that and include `cstdio` too which is the guaranteed way to get access to `std::printf`.

Including `stdio.h` puts `printf` in the global namespace and that is usually not what one wants in C++, so stick with `cstdio`.

It appears your implementation puts `printf` in the global namespace even though you've only included a C++ header. That's unfortunate, but that happens too.

---

Evidence: My preprocessor is called `cpp` and I can use it to list the included header files. I have this program that I've called `std.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {}
```

and if I use `cpp` to list a small subset of the included headers

```
cpp -M std.cpp | tr -d '\\' | tr ' ' '\n' | \
grep -E '^/[^\.]+$' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

I get these C++ headers **on my system**:

```
iostream
ostream
ios
iosfwd
cwchar
exception
typeinfo
new
type_traits
cstdint
clocale
cctype
string
initializer_list
cstdlib
cstdio
cerrno
system_error
stdexcept
streambuf
cwctype
istream
```

and yes, `cstdio` is in there which also includes `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 4):

As [@Ted Lyngmo stated it's implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62533749/6865932), usually `<cstdio>` is included, as is `<cstdlib>`.

My `<iostream>` header file includes:

```
#include <bits/c++config.h>
```

Which in term includes:

```
/* Define if C99 functions or macros in <stdio.h> should be imported in
<cstdio> in namespace std for C++11. */
#define _GLIBCXX11_USE_C99_STDIO 1
```

And

```
/* Define if C99 functions or macros in <stdio.h> should be imported in
<cstdio> in namespace std for C++98. */
#define _GLIBCXX98_USE_C99_STDIO 1
```

The same for `<stdlib.h>`.

Implementation info:

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.0 (tdm64-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open the include file and see the following chain of includes:
**iostream** => **istream** => **ostream** => **ios** => *xlocknum* => **cstdio**

The **cstdio** is C++ wrapper of **stdio.h**

All highlighted names are standard headers, the chain between **ios** and **cstdio** is compiler-dependent (in my case *xlocknum*  is internal from VS2017 compiler)